# How to create BottomSheet in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm trying to get a Persistent BottomSheet in Kotlin. I always get the error message:
The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout

My Gradle File:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.2'
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
    >

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

layout_bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/test">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:text="place:"
        android:id="@+id/place"
        ></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:text="number:"
        android:id="@+id/number"
        ></TextView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="get"
        android:id="@+id/get" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my MainAcitvity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bottomView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet, null)
        val bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = BottomSheetBehavior.from<View>(bottomView)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton)
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            if (bottomSheetBehavior.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            } else {
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know why I always get the error?
I think the view is a child of the CoordinatorLayout

Thanks for your help
Ferdi

Comment: "Child of a CoordinatorLayout" means it is actually nested in the CoordinatorLayout, which would only be true if you put it in the `activity_main` layout file, or manually add it to your `CoordinatorLayout`. You have inflated it but you have not put it in your CoordinatorLayout.

Answer (score 1):

First, just remove layout_behavior attribute from `CoordinatorLayout`.
Then in your `Activity` call the bottom sheet like below:

```
    val btnsheet = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet, null)
    val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this)
    dialog.setContentView(btnsheet)
    dialog.show()
```

I tested this and it will work

Answer (score 0):

The View You are usings as your bottomSheet has to be inside the CoordinatorLayout hosting the bottomSheet.

So Instead of inflating the *layout_bottom_sheet.xml* into a View, you should just include it inside activity_main.xml as a child of the CoordinatorLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
    >

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

     <include
         android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_view"
         layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet.xml"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then in your MainActivity,you can simply get the bottomSheet view by id and do:

```
  val bottomView = findViewById<View>(R.id.bottom_sheet_view)
  val bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = BottomSheetBehavior.from<View>(bottomView)
```

And that should work.

But if for some reason you don't want to add the view directly via XML, you can inflate the view as you have done then add it programmatically.